# Dowloading images random error

Tags: android, cordova

I have the following piece of code:

```
function download_img(imgToDownload, imgToRemove){
            var url = remote_url+imgToDownload; // image url
            root_path   = get_root_path();
            var flag    = "working";
            var flag_delete = false;
            var imageToDownloadPath = root_path + "/" + imgToDownload; // full file path
            var imageToRemovePath = root_path + "/" + imgToRemove; // full file path                        
            try{                 
                var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
                fileTransfer.download(url, imageToDownloadPath, 
                    function () {
                        if(imgToRemove != "" && imgToRemove != null){
                            var entry = new FileEntry("foo", imageToRemovePath);
                            entry.remove(function (){alert("fine");flag_delete = true;}, function (){alert("marron");flag_delete = true;});
                        }
                        else{
                            flag_delete = true;
                        }
                        flag    = "done";
                    }, 
                    function (error) {
                        flag    = "done";
                        flag_delete = true;
                    }
                );
            }catch(error){
                alert("Error capturado: "+error.message);
            }
            while(flag=="working" && !flag_delete){
                try{
                    setTimeout(
                        function() {
                            /* Código */
                        },
                        300
                    );                  
                }
                catch(error){
                    alert("Error en el bucle: " + error.message);
                }

            }
        }
```

I have had problems downloading the files which apparently seemed to be a sync conflict, I mean, looks like something was avorting the execution before the file/s was/were downloaded.

I have used two flags to make sure not to continue until files are downloaded (and old ones deleted if necessary). The idea is to change flag's values when the action is completed and keep the code waiting in a loop.

The results this code is giving is as follows:

- It never seems to enter the success fileTransfer.download sucess method (I used an alert which never triggered) even though the first file downloads properly.
- The flags are never changed so the code stays stuck in the loop, and it does not continue downloading other files.

I think it might be a very basic jQuery behaviour but I am just starting with this technologies and I am a little lost. If anyone could give me a clue on that I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!!